# Odoo 8 POS module.Orderline extend a function

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, odoo

In (odoo8) POS module there's a function **export_as_JSON** in the 
`module.Orderline = Backbone.Model.extend`. How can I extend this specific function. I tried :

```
module.Orderline.extend({
  export_as_JSON: function() {
  debugger;
  return {
     something
  };
}
```

to no avail. Any help to nudge me in right direction is appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by *"there's a function export_as_JSON in the  module.Orderline = Backbone.Model.extend"*..?

Comment: `code`module.Orderline = Backbone.Model.extend({ export_as_JSON: function(){ something}}) `code`   Hope this is a bit more comprehensible. Sorry if the code isnt in the code blocks im still getting used to stackoverflow

Comment: Actually I am just trying via prototyping but that seems as far from correct approach as possible  (module.Orderline.prototype.export_as_JSON = function() {})

Answer (score 2):

Try following:

```
var _initialize_orderline_ = module.Orderline.prototype;
module.Orderline = module.Orderline.extend({

export_as_JSON: function() {
     export_as_JSON_dict=_initialize_orderline_.export_as_JSON.call(this);
        <<your code goes here>>  
        return export_as_JSON_dict;
    },
});
```

Comment: Mr. Hardik i will definitelly try yours out asap when i get some free time (looks like a valid extension to the naked eye), for now It works as in my previous statement with prototyping. i.e.  module.Orderline.prototype.export_as_JSON = function() { code } . Big thanks!